# How to make BASH try and autocomplete on Enter

Tags: bash

I've noticed that for many of the commands I use in bash I have actually learned how many letters of the command I must type before I can press [TAB] to have bash successfully autocomplete the command. For example when opening chromium I dont usually type the whole command but instead type

```
$ chrom[TAB][ENTER]
```

and bash successfully autocompletes the command to `chromium` before I hit the [ENTER] key. Is there a way to make autocomplete work without having to hit [TAB]? My general thinking is that if I type

```
$ chrom[ENTER]
```

bash could check and see that `chrom` isnt a valid command, but it would make sense to autocomplete it to `chromium` since that is the only command that starts with `chrom`

Comment: I prefer having visual feedback which command I execute on the command line, which would be not possible with your suggested autocomplete function. If you want to shorten commonly used commands, you could consider creating an alias: `alias chrom='chromium'` That would even work if you happen to install a programe named `chrome` and correctly launch `chromium`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only an idea, since I feel TAB isn't that hard to hit, muscle memory is an amazing thing.

But if we're going for maximum perverseness:

The BASH shell has a feature involving the 'command_not_found_handler' function, which often is used in many situations as a "Command Not Found" notifier, where it tells you where you might find more information on whatever you mistyped.  This is *often* pre-installed in Ubuntu.

Of course, more information is easily found in the BASH Man Page, try searching for 'not_found'.

This **could** be beaten into submission and used to implement your 'tab-completion-on-fail^H^H^Henter' desire.  Actual code is left as an exercise for the reader.

I fully agree with @Marco above, that I REALLY want the feedback from seeing/knowing what I typed and what I got are substantially similar.

Sounds more like a Microsoft *Innovation* really.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are definitely your friend here, for instance I have:

```
alias code='cd ~/Dropbox/97_2012/work/ror/code'
alias docs='cd ~/Dropbox/97_2012/work/setups'
```

so I can just type

```
$ code
```

or

```
$ docs
```

and I'll get placed in the appropriate directory.

You put these in a `.bash_aliases` file in your home directory ("`~`").

You include this (and this code most likely already exists) in your `.bashrc` file with:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

If you add them and want to see them immediately, either start a new shell session or run your `.bashrc` in your current terminal session, e.g. `. ~/.bashrc` or even just the aliases alone, `. ~/.bash_aliases`

This is better than the approach you initially outlined for a bunch of reasons and is the approach used by the community to give you this functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really what the OP is asking for though. There's no autocompletion involved here, and you'd still have to remember the short commands.

Comment: Good point.  I feel that although they aren't initially looking for this... this might be a good route to take.  The OP may implement an answer that does auto-complete and presses [RETURN] and may then find that unintended commands get executed which can be hazardous.  Think of  delete link with no confirm, a well known problem. That experience may then lead the OP to 'want' to press return and may then like a short alias that will reduce their typing.  Maybe!  So I am giving information to try and help them going down that path.